# NUT not shutting down UPS. Does 14.04 server block USB comms in runlevel 0?

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed Network UPS Tools (nut) on my new ubuntu 14.04 64-bit server. I used the exact same conf files that I had on my old Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit server.

Everything went well except that when I tested the 14.04 server for automatic shutdowns by giving the command

```
sudo upsmon -c fsd
```

the UPS did not turn off the load when the system was brought down by nut and therefore, the server never restarted.

It turns out that the nut version on my 14.04 server has different (newer) init scripts than the one on the 12.04 server. So I thought, maybe there is a bug on these newer scrips.

To try and figure out what was happening, I disconnected the server from the UPS power outlet and connected it directly to the utility power outlet, but left the USB connection on and booted it up. I then sent the following command from the terminal console:

```
sudo /sbin/upsdrvctl shutdown
```

The UPS turned off the load, and a little while later, turned it on again as it should.

Next, I temporarily modified the /etc/init.d/halt script by replacing this section of code:

```
    # See if we need to cut the power.
    if [ "$INIT_HALT" = "POWEROFF" ] && [ -x /etc/init.d/ups-monitor ]
    then
            /etc/init.d/ups-monitor poweroff
    fi
```

with this:

```
    /sbin/upsdrvctl shutdown
```

The original code calls "ups-monitor" which is a link to script "nut-client" which, after doing some checks, calls script "nut-server" which in turn issues the command "/sbin/upsdrvctl shutdown" to shutdown the UPS load.

So now, with this temporary mod, the nut scripts where out of the way. However when I gave the command

```
sudo upsmon -c fsd
```

the system went down but once again the UPS did not turn off the load.

Could it be that the Ubuntu server 14.04 is blocking USB communications on runlevel 0 when the halt script is running???